# Displaying PDF file in ASP.NET without stopping the request

Tags: asp.net

I am providing a PDF file to the user in an ASP.NET application.  I have included the code I am using the do this.  This works great if that's the only thing I'm doing on that request.  What I would really like to do is show provide this PDF file on Form Load without affecting any of the other stuff in the Form Load event.  Can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong in the code?  Thanks!!

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = file.ContentType;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", file.OriginalFileName));
Response.TransmitFile(Path.Combine("C:\", file.FileName));
Response.End();
```

Comment: Can you rephrase the following as I don't get precisely what it is you're asking:
"What I would really like to do is show provide this PDF file on Form Load without affecting any of the other stuff in the Form Load event."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, I'd probably use a separate page, and also don't use the standard asp.net pipeline, consider using a custom [httphandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3ff8w4a%28VS.71%29.aspx) for pdf's instead, also Phil Haack has a great [template](http://haacked.com/archive/2005/03/17/AnAbstractBoilerplateHttpHandler.aspx) to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

`Response.End()` will throw an `ThreadAbortException` and nothing else will execute. Literally that *ends* page output.

I recommend you to create another page to generate your PDF file; if you need to send parameters, you could to send them through querystring.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a separate page for the PDF download.

You can just call the PDF generation page after the form submits (with javascript, a meta refresh, iframe, etc).  The effect will be that the form posts, and does whatever, then the PDF download box will appear.